# PySpark Transformation on column with Json

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a column with a JSON array and I'm trying to create a new column with only a partial amount of the JSON plus some potential transforms on the json data. I'm using the following DataBricks page as a reference.

https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/_static/notebooks/transform-complex-data-types-python.html

| ID | js1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"a":1, "b":1} |

And I want to return:

| ID | js1 | js2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"a":1, "b":1}] | [{"a":1}] |

I'm using slightly cut down version of the sudo-method below for brevity.

```
def my_method(js):
    reader = spark.read
    reader.schema(schema) #Schema provided
    json = reader.json([js]) <-- Error here 

    return lit(str(json["a"]))

df.withColumn("js2", my_method(col("js1")))
```

The error I'm getting is `Column not iterable`. So how would I be able to transform the contents of the JSON method and return using withColumn a transformed block of JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of accessing using `[name]` you need to use the [map_filter function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_filter.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_filter), like this (adjust the list of possible values):

```
df.select(map_filter(
    "js1", lambda k, _: (k == 'a') | (k == 'c')).alias("js2")
)
```

P.S. You can't use `spark.read` from inside of the user-defined function